# Proving a topological space is not first countable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $p \in X$. We define a topology on $X$:

$$\tau := \{U | U \subset X \wedge (U^{C} \textrm{is finite} \vee p \in U^{C} \}$$

Show that if $X$ is uncountable, then $p$ does not have a countable basis for its neighborhoods.

Some relevant things I've noticed:

1. The intersection of all sets of a basis must be equal to $\{ p \}$
2. It's evident from the topology on $X$ that the basis must contain every point in $X$.

I've tried to establish a contradiction by finding a different point in the intersection but I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alright, so apparently it's alright to consider only open sets as basis elements. Since any two open sets from $\tau$ contain all elements from $X$ except a finite number it follows that their intersection if infinite. By induction it follows that any countable intersection of open sets is in fact uncountable which is a contradiction. Agree/disagree?

Answer (score 1):

The only neighborhoods of $p$ are sets with a finite complement. Assume that $U_1, U_2, ...$ is a countable family of sets each of which contains $p$, such that $X-U_i=\{x_i^1,x_i^2,...,x_i^{N_i}\}$. If these sets formed a local base at $p$, then any neighborhood would contain some $U_i$. In other words, any finite set had to be a subset of some of the sets $\{x^1_i,x^2_i,...,x^{N_i}_i\}$. Since the union $\bigcup_i X-U_i$ is countable, there is a point $x\ne x_i^k$ for any $k,i$, so this is not possible.